# Is the Euclidean valuation on a Euclidean domain unique?

Tags: ring-theory

I have just started studying Euclidean domain which is defined as follows :

An integral domain $R$ is called a Euclidean domain if there exists a function $\delta : R \setminus {\{0\}} \longrightarrow \mathbb {N_{0}}$ which satisfies the following properties.

(1) $\delta (a) \leq \delta (ab)$, for all $a,b \in R \setminus {\{0\}}$.

(2) For any $a,b \in R$ with $b \neq 0$ there exist $q,r \in R$ such that $a = bq + r$, where either $r = 0$ or $\delta (r) < \delta (b)$.

Here $q$ is called quotient and $r$ is called remainder.

The function $\delta$ is called a Euclidean norm function (or Euclidean valuation) on $R$.

Now my question is :

Is such Euclidean valuation on a Euclidean domain unique?

I am in a fix.Please tell me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  For instance, if $\delta$ is a Euclidean valuation on $R$, then so is the function $\delta'$ defined by $\delta'(a)=\delta(a)+1$.

Answer (score 1):

Another example (to show non-uniqueness): On the ring of integers, define $\delta (x) = x^2$.

Answer (score 0):

I have another example too :D

I suppose that you must be aware that in $K[X]$ (here $K$ is a field) the degree of a polynomial $\deg$ is used to defined an euclidean valuation. Just take $\delta(p(x))=\deg(p(x))$, where $p(x)\in K[x]$. But it turn outs that we can define $\delta(p(x))=2^{\deg(p(x))}$ and this is an euclidean valuation too.

Last example is given in N. Jacobson's book "**Basic Algebra I**", exactly after definition 2.5. The advantages of this euclidean valuation is that we can define it even for the zero polynomial. Just take the convention $\deg(0)=-\infty$ and $2^{-\infty}=0$. Also, this euclidean valuation is *multiplicative*, i.e., $\delta(ab)=\delta(a)\delta(b)$.